# How to Write a Variable to File in Perl

Tags: perl

I have info contained in a variable that I need to have written to a file. My script needs to be create the file and then write to it.

Here's my current script:

```
my $file_location = '/network/$custom_directory/$custom_filename';
open(my $file ">", $file_location) or die $!;
print $file "$variable_data";
close $file;
```

I'm getting the feeling that my script is getting hung up on the actual file creation, rather than the variable-writing process. 
The error I get when I run the script is: 'No such file or directory' at the line where I try to open the file.

Comment: What happens that causes you to "get that feeling"?

Comment: Show us the error you got

Comment: Is that the entire script?  If so, then `$variable_data` is not getting set anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your programme. All three arguments of `open` must be separated by commas.

```
open my $file, '>', $file_location or die $!;
```

Single quotes do not interpolate, unlike double quotes, so you probably need them in the file path:

```
my $file_location = "/network/$custom_directory/$custom_filename";
```

BTW: Including a sole variable into double quotes server no purpose for string contents. You can equivalently

```
print $file $variable_data;
```

Comment: No, the arguments to a function are not **delimited** by commas. They are **separated** by commas and optionally **delimited** by parentheses.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. The double quotes park makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You didn’t say what your error is.

- But you’re missing a comma.
- You also have the wrong quotes.
- You also (probably) forgot the newline at the end.
- And you forgot to check that the close succeeded lest your filesystem should have filled up.
- You may have forgotten the binmode or the encoding.

Which gives you something like this, with obligatory preamble:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $custom_directory = "something old";
my $custom_filename  = "something new";
my $data             = "something borrowed";

my $path = "/network/$custom_directory/$custom_filename";

open(my $handle, ">", $path)    || die "can't open $path: $!";
binmode($handle);               # for raw; else set the encoding

print $handle "$data\n";

close($handle)                  || die "can't close $path: $!";
```

Answer (score 3):

Two things: First the file location is in single-quotes, so the `$` variables won't be interpolated. Second, you're missing a comma in the call to `open`. The code should read:

```
my $file_location = "/network/$custom_directory/$custom_filename";
open(my $file, ">", $file_location) or die $!;
```

Answer (score 3):

First,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

may help. Second, variable interpolation requires double quoted strings:

```
my $file_location = "/network/$custom_directory/$custom_filename";
```

Third, you may probably need a \n at the print statement:

```
print $file "$variable_data\n";
```

And finally, your open statement should be:

```
open my $file, ">", $file_location or die $!;
```